# What is the Inverse function of $y = 10^{-x}$? Steps are appreciated.

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-function, inverse

What is the inverse of $y = 10^{-x}$?

These are my steps for the problem.

**Step 1**   $y = 10^{-x}$.

**Step 2**   $x = 10^{-y}$ by inverse substitution.

**Step 3**   $10^y(x) = 1$.

**Step 4**   $10^y = \frac{1}{x}$.

**Step 5**   $y = \log \frac{1}{x}$.

**Step 6**   $y = -\log x$.

Then how is the inverse $y = 10^{-x}$? I do not understand why $- \log x$ is equal to $10^{-x}$.

Comment: Please clean up your question and use MathJax

Comment: You might want to specify $\log$ as $\log_{10}$

Comment: I'm new to this website, so your edits are more than just helpful, they're essential. This is a easy problem, but I was confused by looking at the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion begins with step $2$. Not that the step is wrong but the way you have proceeded and the problem you are facing is due to that step only. So better leave that step out and follow the next steps accordingly.

From $$y=f(x)=10^{-x}$$ we can say that $$-x=\log_{10}y$$ or $$x=\log_{10} \frac{1}{y}$$

From above we can say that $$x=f^{-1}y$$
So $$f^{-1}y=\log_{10} \frac{1}{y}$$
or $$\color{red}{f^{-1}x=\log_{10} \frac{1}{x}}$$
where $f^{-1}x$ is the inverse function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this can be further simplified to - log x. right? Since log 1/ x = 0 - log x.

Comment: @KingKONG Yes surely. Only that a minus sign in front of a log function steals its beauty. :-)

Comment: This is more of a question rather than a comment, but do (pure) mathematicians prefer $\log_{10}(x)$ or $\frac{\ln x}{\ln 10}$?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 the first notation is specifically used in common algebraic calculations and hence is called common logarithm whereas ln is called natural logarithm and is used in calculus mainly. However there is no strict rules regarding the choice one makes.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 It depends on what you want really. Often $\log x = \ln x$ is used where an arbitrary logarithm could be used just by habit, since it's such a common function to deal with. However, it doesn't really matter which you choose, and I often use both... it's pretty contextual

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen $\log x= \ln x$ ?? Really ??

Comment: @SchrodingersCat $log$ has a place in calculus too, although it's not used nearly as much as $ln$

Comment: @S.Mo Yes,there might be... I just pointed out the major differences. Nothing else....Point taken.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Notationally, yes. In mathematics these are both used to represent the same function depending on the author. I was pointing out that you see the function written both ways, and both represent the inverse of the exponential function. Perhaps a bit overkill, but I rarely see $\ln x$ used in more formal math settings... in higher math you almost always work with solely the natural logarithm and so it makes sense to simply refer to it as "\$\log$"

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I knew that writing $\log$ implies the base is $10$ while in $\ln$ the base is $e$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat This is common among engineering and science, but not among higher Mathematics.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) for a little more on this from a much more reputable source than me :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not assume they are equal to be inverses. The two functions $10^{-x}$ and $-\log x$ are inverses of each other $x>0$ because $$10^{-(-\log_{10} x)} = 10^{\log_{10} x} = x >0,$$ and $$-\log_{10} (10^{-x}) = -(-x)\log_{10}(10) = x.$$

Comment: so the inverse is  not 10^ -x

Answer (score 0):

To get the inverse function we first switch $x$ and $y$ to get
$$x = 10^{-y}$$
Solving for this by taking the $\log$ of both sides and multiplying by $-1$, we get that
$$y = -\log_{10} (x)$$
This is the inverse function to  $y=10^{-x}$
Note that we can check this by plugging it back in. $10^{-(-\log_{10})} = 10^{\log_{10} x} = x$ by identity. What you are confusing is that $y$ is an arbitrary variable... if you have two functions $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ that does **not** mean that $f(x) = g(x)$. For example, let's take $y=5x$ and $y=x^2$. These describe two independent functions... we just use the variable $y$ for both. Obviously $5x \neq x^2$

Comment: $10^{\log_{10}x} = x$ :)

Comment: @pyrazolam *hangs head in shame... corrects dumb mistake and sneaks away*

Comment: where'd the $-1$ go?

Comment: @S.Mo -_- Thanks. I'm all over the place with this one... I don't know what was going through my head when I wrote this. I checked back through for mistakes... should be good. The important part at the end checks out though. Nice catch :/,

Comment: No problem; I think the problem can be done without all the complications of functions though. Your answer is definitely correct, but the arguments can be made using simple algebraic and logarithmic rules.

Comment: yeah. I confirmed it. It is correct.

Comment: @S.Mo True, finding the answer requires only basic algebra, and once one finds the answer it is clear equality does not hold between inverses of functions. I merely wanted to explain that the OP should never expect this without good reason.

Comment: Yeah, I think what OP did is pretty much fine, but he should just specify the domain at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear the inverse is $-\log_{10}x$, and you had to check that $y = 10^{-x}$ is one-to-one, but other than that, what did is fine. You showed that the inverse of $y= 10^{-x}$ is $y = -\log_{10} x$. In general inverses are not equal. In $\mathbb R^2$, I believe you can take the inverse to be a reflection about the line $y = x$. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function).
[image]

Comment: What's that app you used?

Comment: @tyr I googled "graphing" and this [site](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) came up.

Comment: The Application is known as the Desmos Graphing Calculator. It supports all your basic elementary functions, a few special functions, derivatives, custom-defined variables, simple one-variable equations, value-sliders, etc

Answer (score 0):

$$y=10^{-x}$$
$$lny=-xln10$$
$$\frac{lny}{ln10}=-x$$
$$log_{10}y=-x$$
$$x=- log_{10}y $$